# Use of ' in SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was doing some php;
I found that the following code works

```
function get_total_urls() {    
    $total = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`url_key`) FROM `urls`');
    return (int)mysql_result($total, 0);
}
get_total_urls();
```

But following code shows warning

```
function get_total_urls() {    
    $total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('url_key') FROM 'urls'");
    return (int)mysql_result($total, 0);
}
get_total_urls();
```

Shows the following warning:

**Warning**: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.

Please help; why the 2nd code shows warning but 1st code is ok? The 2nd code fails to get the count of 'url_key' from database table.

---

Is there anyway to write the first code without back-tick and it will work perfectly?

Comment: That's the difference between an apostrophe and a backtick. In MySQL this carries meaning ... Backticks describe identifiers, whereas apostrophes mark strings.

Comment: The 2 queries are total different things. Use `'` for static strings and backticks to escape table and column names

Comment: MySQL has it's own way also when it comes to delimiters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your statement:

```
$total = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`url_key`) FROM `urls`');
```

In MySQL, backticks are used to delimit identifiers -- when they conflict with reserved words or contain unseemly characters (such as spaces, periods, commas, and so on).  Because it is a good idea to have identifiers that do not conflict with reserved words and that contain no unseemly characters, backticks are rarely needed.

You can just write:

```
$total = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(url_key) FROM urls');
```

Single quotes should *only* be used for string and date constants.  Do not use them for identifiers, they just lead to confusion.  As you have no doubt noticed.

Comment: ...although you probably shouldn't be using a deprecated API

Answer (score 2):

Both the codes are different.

`Backticks` are to be used for table and column identifiers,

The same as in your example; where `url_key` is a column name and `urls` is a table_name.

```
$total = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`url_key`) FROM `urls`');
```

But `Backticks` are only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set.

It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

**'Single quotes'** should be used for string values like in the `VALUES()` list in insert statement.

Ex:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `col1`, `col2`, `date_field`) VALUES (NULL, 'val1', 'val2', '2015-01-28')";
```

MySQL also expects `DATE` and `DATETIME` literal values to be single-quoted as strings like `'2001-01-01 00:00:00'`

Double quotes are also supported by MySQL for string values as well, but single quotes are more widely accepted by other RDBMS, so it is a good habit to use single quotes instead of double.

Find more explanation on this with similar example:
[When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks/11321508#11321508)